# R A simple univariate plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to do a simple graph like this:

```
ff<-data.frame(Freq=c(rep(10000,10),rep(100,15),rep(10,50),rep(1,100)))
plot(log(ff$Freq),type="l")
```

is the only option to add a x variable?

```
require(ggplot2)
ff$Ord <- 1:nrow(ff)
ggplot(data=ff,aes(x=Ord,y=log(Freq))) + geom_line()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes that's fine, but I wonder if there was another way.

Comment: That's right, I was reading the ggplot book but I didn't find nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach with geom_step():

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(ff, aes(x = seq_along(Freq), y = log10(Freq))) + geom_step(size = 1) +
   labs(x = "Index", y = "Freq") +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = math_format(10^.x))
```

Comment: I prefer the @Arun simpler approach but this is another way as I asked, thanks.